# File path not loading

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I have a java web app running tomcat7. I have a servlet that renders images. I am attemping to use the [File class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html). However, it will return false when I call exists() like so

```
imageFile = new File(filesDir + "images/", id + "_" + size + "." + file_extension);

// Check if file actually exists in filesystem.
if (!imageFile.exists()) {
   // render 404
}
```

I have hardcoded the dir into the code to assure that it is actually pointing to the file. I am using the "/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/files/images/" directory. After reading documentation for the file class it states:

"This directory is named by the system property user.dir, and is typically the directory in which the Java virtual machine was invoked".

How do I give java the permissions to load such directory? Or is there a better directory I should be placing my files?

```
Edit "ps -ef | grep tomcat"

tomcat   16099     1  0 Nov22 ?        00:07:03 /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -classpath /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/tomcat7 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat7 -Djava.endorsed.dirs= -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/cache/tomcat7/temp -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
root     18217 18179  0 18:00 pts/0    00:00:00 vi /usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out
root     18376 18364  0 18:11 pts/2    00:00:00 grep tomcat
root     22805     1  0 Sep10 ?        02:22:53 /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.2.0/java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.2.0/apache-tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=32m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xss2m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.2.0/apache-tomcat/endorsed -classpath /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.2.0/apache-tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.2.0/apache-tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.2.0/apache-tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.2.0/apache-tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Comment: Why are you using `URLDecoder.decode()`?

Comment: After reading the javadoc for it. I don't need it. I will take it out and run it. I wouldn't assume it to be causing the problem. However, we will see

Comment: If you're using an absolute path (`/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/files/images/`), then you're not using the current directory (`user.dir`). The current directory is only used for relative paths.

Comment: I have tried using both the relative path and absolute. Neither will will return exists() == true. What else could be preventing the file from loading?

Comment: After sout using getAbsolutePath() it outputted " /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/files/images/19_medium.jpg". Using ssh I confirmed the file folder / location to be correct. Are there permission issues that could be a causing problems? Folders / files are chmod 0777 at the moment

Comment: Edit: forgot to remove the urldecoder last param

Comment: What user is your tomcat running under? If you are using nobody, then you can not write anywhere outside the app path. Do "ps -ef | grep tomcat" and find the user and see if the user have permission to read the directory/file.

Comment: I see the home folder is placed to tomcat7, however I do not know what I am looking for permission wise from this output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was what @gmansoor was mentioning. The tomcat server did not have permissions to access the directory. I moved my files to "/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/files/". The webapps folder is specified in the catalina.properties file. After that I chmod 777 the files directory which allow java to open the file.